# Test if flash is on/off in Espresso / UiAutomator test

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-uiautomator, camera-flash

I am writting some tests regarding the open/close of the flash to allow better images capturing from the camera.

How can I know inside an Espresso/UiAutomator test if the flash is on or off?

Comment: Are you trying to detect if it is currently on during a live capture or if it was on? Do you have access to a CameraCaptureSession or CaptureResult? If a solution does exist, it'll be in the Camera2 API: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary

Comment: No @MikeCollins, in the test we are out of the normal activity scope, so there is no access to the Camera2 API as far as I know.

Comment: I figured as much. I looked pretty hard and couldn’t find anything. There’s nothing in Espresso for this and adb output didn’t reveal anything useful for state, only existence.